# PHP Fatal error: Interface not found, using factory pattern with namespaces

Tags: php, design-patterns, interface

File 1 - `/Users/jitendraojha/www/DesignPatternsWithPhpLanguage/FactoryPattern/FactoryClassPattern/UserInterface.php`

```
<?php

namespace DesignPatternsWithPhpLanguage\FactoryPattern\FactoryClassPattern;

interface UserInterface
{

    function setFirstName($firstName);
    function getFirstName();
}

?>
```

File 2 - `/Users/jitendraojha/www/DesignPatternsWithPhpLanguage/FactoryPattern/FactoryClassPattern/User.php`

```
<?php

namespace DesignPatternsWithPhpLanguage\FactoryPattern\FactoryClassPattern;


class User implements UserInterface
{

    private $firstName = null;

    public function __construct($params) {   }

    public function setFirstName($firstName)
    {

        $this->firstName = $firstName;
    }

    public function getFirstName()
    {

        return $this->firstName;
    }
}

?>
```

**Problem**

`php FactoryPattern/FactoryClassPattern/UserInterface.php` - Runs fine.

`php FactoryPattern/FactoryClassPattern/User.php` - gives following errors: *PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'DesignPatternsWithPhpLanguage\FactoryPattern\FactoryClassPattern\UserInterface' not found in /Users/jitendraojha/www/DesignPatternsWithPhpLanguage/FactoryPattern/FactoryClassPattern/User.php on line 7*

I had `use UserInterface;` added in File 2 with no solution.

Comment: The problem is in `User.php`, which you didn't add to your question. Could you add that file too?

Comment: @Kenney - See file - 2 - that is `User.php`.

Comment: Ow I'm sorry! - no idea why I didn't get that...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All you need its include, but better yet you should use an autoloader

See example below for quick test with include, assumption here is both files are in the same directory.

```
namespace DesignPatternsWithPhpLanguage\FactoryPattern\FactoryClassPattern;

include('UserInterface.php');

class User implements UserInterface
{

    private $firstName = null;

    public function __construct($params) {   }

    public function setFirstName($firstName)
    {

       $this->firstName = $firstName;
    }

    public function getFirstName()
    {

       return $this->firstName;
     }
```

}

```
// Quick test will - output ===> John
$user = new User(null);
$user->setFirstName('John');
echo $user->getFirstName();
```

Comment: Hey, That worked but how do I get `use UserInterface;` in file2 working?

Comment: Got it, will have to implement one autoloader method, this is the drawback of being dependent on frameworks . :( https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the UserInterface.php file before the User.php file.